# Display specifics columns of each rows in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, frontend

I have been working on a job-listing website during the last few weeks as a self taught CS student. I finished the front end of the website in July and now I am learning mySQL and PHP to produce the back-end.

So, on the current "job listing" page `search.html`, there is currently 4 listing in the page but I typed those directly on the `html` when I was making the front-end just to see how it will look like.

[image: Front ends]

I have build my database like this and added few examples:

[image: database structure]

I also made a back-end page to let the user add a a new listing and it is working.

[image: backend-client side]

I am not sure it was a good idea to start with the front-end. I am now trying to display three columns (`title, location, type) of each`row`based on my specific front-end layout. I won't display the`date` yet since I have not created it on mySQL.

**search.html**

```
  <div class="job-listing">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="job-number">
                    <h2>We Found <span id="number-jobs-total" class="text-secondary"></span> Offers For <span>You</span> </h2>
                </div>
                <ul class="job-board">
                    <li class="job job-1">
                        <div class="job-title">
                            <h2>Process Engineer</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-location">
                            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-type">
                            <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-date">
                            <p>Published on 07/19/2019</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-industry">
                            <p>Engineering</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="job-keywords">
                            <li>Engineering</li>
                            <li>Science</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="job job-2">
                            <div class="job-title">
                                <h2>Chief Financial Officier</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="job-location">
                                <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="job-type">
                                    <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="job-date">
                                    <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="job job-3">
                                <div class="job-title">
                                    <h2>Assistant CEO</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-location">
                                    <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-type">
                                        <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-date">
                                        <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="job job-4">
                                    <div class="job-title">
                                        <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-location">
                                        <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-type">
                                            <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-date">
                                            <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>          
                </ul>
                <nav class="pagination-container">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Previous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Next</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Things I will do later:

- I need to protect my PHP code against injections
- The pagination button is not working

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is the help you expect form the community. But according to the requirement what you have to do is that need to fetch data from DB and then those data to be display in the front-end page. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp. If you need more help please feel free to comment

Comment: Did you try something for fetching data from database , post that as well.